# How can Restrict URL or Links to Show within Wordpress Excerpt

Tags: wordpress, post

Hi i created code to show excerpt in my wordpress theme but when in put the urls within my post show them in my excerpt this is my code

```
<div class="standard-excerpt">
    <?php
        $content = get_the_content();
        $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 200 );
        echo $trimmed_content;
    ?>
        <a class="text-info" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php _e('[Continue Reading]', 'Yallanpe Theme'); ?>
        </a>
</div>
```

how i can restrict the URL or Links Until don't show them in my excerpt?
does i can do this by `preg_match_all` ? or no? if i can how can i do this?
please i want modify the `$trimmed_content` Until don't show me the Url and Links in my excerpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the PHP function [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). Try this:

```
<div class="standard-excerpt">
    <?php
        $content = strip_tags( get_the_content() );
        $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content , 200 );
        echo $trimmed_content;
    ?>
        <a class="text-info" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php _e('[Continue Reading]', 'Yallanpe Theme'); ?>
        </a>
</div>
```

NOTE: this wont remove the words between the `<a>` tags, just stop them being clickable

Comment: not work with me the output only is array(); and don't show any other excerpt words

Comment: @ShwanNamiq try with updated code.. (moved the tag stripping to around the `get_the_content()` call)

Comment: if you can please modify my code bu using preg_matche_all for restrict the lnks and urls to show with my excerpt code i don't want use srtip_tags function because also show links and urls

Comment: i mention that this would be the case in the 'NOTE' of my answer. depending how you write your content, removing the links entirely could read weirdly. as per this very famous answer about html and regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/648350 .. it shouldnt be done